# The term 'nodemon' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

i am new in nodejs, when i try to run program i am getting an error like "the term nodemon is not recognized the name of cmdlet,function,script file or operable function" please help

> index.js

```
 // Thos is node server Node server which will handle socket io
    // if new user is joined then socket.io fire
    
    const io = require('socket.io')(7000)
    
    const users = {};
    
    io.on('connection', socket =>{
        socket.on('new-user-joined',name => {
            // console.log('New User', name);
            users[socket.id] = name;
            socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined',name)
        });
    
        //if someone send the message,it call to other people
        socket.on('send', message => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('receive',{message: message, name: users[socket.id]})
        });
    
       // if someone leave the chat let other know
        socket.on('disconnect', message => {
            socket.broadcast.emit('left',users[socket.id]);
            delete users[socket.id];
        });
    });
```

> client.js

here is my client file where i define my all task like where should be message receive,where should be message send etc

```
   const socket = io('http://localhost:7000');


const form = document.getElementById('send-container');
const messageInput = document.getElementById('messageInp');
const messageContainer = document.querySelector('.container');


var audio = new Audio('whistle.mp3');

const append = (message,position) => {
    const messageElement = document.createElement('div')
    messageElement.innerText = message;
    messageElement.classList.add('message');
    messageElement.classList.add(position);
    messageContainer.append(messageElement);
    if(position =='left'){
    audio.play();
    }
}


 const name = prompt("Enter Your Name to join");
socket.emit('new-user-joined',name)


socket.on('user-joined', name =>{
    append(`${name} joined the chat`,'right');
})

socket.on('receive', data =>{
    append(`${data.name}: ${data.message}`,'left');
})



socket.on('left', name =>{
    append(`${name}: left the chat`,'right');
})


form.addEventListener('submit',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const message = messageInput.value;
    append(`You: ${message}`, 'right');
    socket.emit('send',message);
    messageInput.value = '';
})
```

Comment: Have you installed nodemon?

Comment: Try running "npm i nodemon -g" to install nodemon

Comment: The code has nothing to do with nodemon. Try running `$ npm g -i nodemon`

Comment: @AdamAzad It's probably best not to include `$` in command examples.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I always thought `$` mean terminal even though I use Windows myself, ay? ;)

Comment: thanks guys for help

Answer (score 1):

You could setup nodemon for a single project like below.

1. `npm init -y`

This will create package.json file in project's root directory

2. `npm install nodemon`
3. In the package.json file... under scripts add this...

[image]

Notice how I added

```
"server" : "nodemon server.js"
```

Save this package.json file

Then in terminal... run

```
npm run server
```

Then nodemon will start running... and track changes.